# CXF unmarshalling Date not accepting NULL value

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

I have a WSDL file containing -

```
<xs:complexType name="PNV">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="dataType" type="xsd:int" />
            <xs:element name="multiValued" type="xsd:boolean" />
            <xs:element name="booleanValue" type="xsd:boolean" />
            <xs:element name="dateValue" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime" />
            ..........
```

and it is converted to Java file like this -

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "PNV", propOrder = {
    "dataType",
    "multiValued",
    "booleanValue",
    "dateValue",

})
public class PNV
    implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected int dataType;
    protected boolean multiValued;
    protected boolean booleanValue;
    @XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class, nillable = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1 .class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected Date dateValue;

}
```

binding file -

```
<jaxws:bindings  node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='http://changeservice.xxservices.service.xx']">      
    <jxb:globalBindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">        
    <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:dateTime" 
                  parseMethod="org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.parseDateTime"
                  printMethod="org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.printDateTime"/>    
        <jxb:serializable uid="1"/>     
    </jxb:globalBindings>  
</jaxws:bindings>
```

in my SOAPUI Test case I passed -

```
<dateValue nil="true"/>
```

but it gave me following error -

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parseAndSetYear(XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java:2891) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parse(XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java:2777) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.<init>(XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java:436) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl.newXMLGregorianCalendar(DatatypeFactoryImpl.java:536) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseDateTime(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.parseDateTime(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:417) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(DatatypeConverter.java:327) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.parseDateTime(DataTypeAdapter.java:65) ~[cxf-xjc-runtime-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.w3._2001.xmlschema.Adapter1.unmarshal(Adapter1.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.w3._2001.xmlschema.Adapter1.unmarshal(Adapter1.java:1) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.AdaptedAccessor.set(AdaptedAccessor.java:55) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    ... 107 common frames omitted
```

I checked the date attribute in Adapter1 class and it is coming as blank instead of null so it's throwing an error. My Question is why it is not taking NULL value even though I am passing nil=true in my SOAPUI test case. why it is coming as blank? I also tried to completely remove this dateValue field from my input request and its still giving me same error for date field.

I also tried to use XMLGregorianCalendar as a type of dateValue but when I passed nil=true in SOAPUI it's giving me same error message.. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link helped me:
https://blogs.oracle.com/rammenon/specifying-null-content-in-your-xml-document-using-nillable-and-xsi:nil

I added xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance in my SOAPUI test & added date Value as

```
<dateValue xsi:nil="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to change wsdl file (in case in supplied by external system), you can override standard org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter

Root of the issue is not null but empty string, coming as input parameter to the parseDateTime method.

1. create class similar to the "org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter" with extra check for empty string

   ```
    public class DateAdapter  {

    public static Date parseDateTime(String s) {
        if (s == null||s.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        return DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(s).getTime();
    }
    public static String printDateTime(Date dt) {
        if (dt == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(dt);
        return DatatypeConverter.printDateTime(c);
    }
   ```

   }
2. specify the new class in the binding file

```xml
    <jaxws:bindings  node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='http://changeservice.xxservices.service.xx']">      
        <jxb:globalBindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">        
        <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:dateTime" 
                      parseMethod="your_class_here.parseDateTime"
                      printMethod="your_class_here.printDateTime"/>    
            <jxb:serializable uid="1"/>     
        </jxb:globalBindings>  
    </jaxws:bindings>
```